Prevent auto HTML tag closure when streaming data into tiptap editor?
I'm working on an application where I'm supposed to render text coming in stream into a Tiptap editor. I'm setting the content  as I receive the data from the backend. On setting the data using the setContent function, the editor either auto closes the HTML tag or inserts a p tag by itself.
Here's an example:
Let's consider each array item within the array as streaming data.
const data = [            // ↓ editor converts into this format
        '<h1>Random ', // <h1>Random</h1>
        'HTML Sni', // <p>HTML Sni</p>
        'ppet</h1>', //<p>ppet</p>
        '<p>This is', //<p>This is</p>
        'a random', //<p>a random</p>
        'HTML snippet</p>', //<p>HTML snippet</p>
        '<p>It is used to', //<p>It is used to</p>
        'test the editor<', //<p>test the editor&lt;</p>
        '/p>', //<p></p>
      ];

Actual output:
<p></p><h1>Random</h1><p>HTML Sni</p><p>ppet</p><p>This is</p><p>a random</p><p>HTML snippet</p><p></p><p>It is used to</p><p>test the editor&lt;</p>
Desired output:
<h1>Random HTML Snippet</h1><p>This is a random HTML snippet</p><p>It is used to test the editor</p>
How can I achieve the desired output?
I believe I'll need to create a custom extension but I'm not sure where to start.
